# How to Find Certificates by Issuer

Tags: c#, loops, certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to loop through the Certificate store and identify if a certificate has a specific issuer. I located [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.issuername%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article which provides the example of calling the certificates issuer:

```
            Console.WriteLine("{0}Issuer: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.Issuer);
```

But their example appears to require an input certificate. Is it possible to loop through the Certificates to identify if there are any on a machine that have the specific issuer?
Something like:

```
ForEach(cert in x509certificate2.store)
{
    if (cert.issuer == SpecificIssuer)
    {
        console.writeline(cert.ToString());
    }
}
```

The certificates I'm trying to isolate will belong to specific stores (?) such as [Console Root\Certificates (Local Computer)\Personal\Certificates] if it is possible to further filter the loops scope to just these specific stores.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Certificates.Find(), use the StoreName to specify your own store.

```
X509Store Store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection CertColl = Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "Microsoft",true);
foreach (X509Certificate2 Cert in CertColl)
    Console.WriteLine("Cert: " + Cert.IssuerName.Name);
```